# .NETCore service.Configure appsettings with dynamic / JObject

Tags: .net, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

My app reads the appsettings.json file in services startup.cs

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSettings("somedata")
```

After reading, I'm serving the data while service the JS files.

My quiestion is - **there's possible way to read in this way the appsettings and some of the poco will declared as dynamic/JObject?**

The appsettings format can changed and the js is ready for this cases.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind netcore IConfigurationSection to a dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007146/bind-netcore-iconfigurationsection-to-a-dynamic-object)