# Fail to serialize IConfigurationSection from Json

Tags: c#, json.net

I have following Json-based configuration file:

```
{
  "PostProcessing": {
    "ValidationHandlerConfiguration": {
      "MinimumTrustLevel": 80,
      "MinimumMatchingTrustLevel": 75
    },
    "MatchingCharacterRemovals": [
      "-",
      "''",
      ":"
    ]
  },
  "Processing": {
    "OrderSelection": {
      "SelectionDaysInterval": 30,
      "SelectionDaysMaximum": 365
    }
  }
}
```

As serialization framework I use **Newtonsoft**. To serialize this config into objects I have implemented following classes:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class RecognitionConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PostProcessing", Required = Required.Always)]
    public PostRecognitionConfiguration PostRecognitionConfiguration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Processing", Required = Required.Always)]
    public ProcessRecognitionConfiguration ProcessRecognitionConfiguration { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class PostRecognitionConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ValidationHandlerConfiguration ValidationHandlerConfiguration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty] public List<string> MatchingCharacterRemovals { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ProcessRecognitionConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "OrderSelection", Required = Required.Always)]
    public OrderSelectionConfiguration OrderSelectionConfiguration { get; set; }
}
```

In a class I try to serialize a specific configuration section into these class structures using **IConfigurationSection.Get()**.

```
var serializedConfiguration = this.ConfigurationSection.Get<RecognitionConfiguration>();
```

But when I debug the code, I always get an "empty" variable **serializedConfiguration** which is not null, but all properties are null.

[image]

If I use

```
this.ConfigurationSection.GetSection("Processing").Get<ProcessRecognitionConfiguration>()
```

or change the naming of the properties in the json file to exactly match the property names in the classes like this:

```
{   
  "ProcessRecognitionConfiguration": {
    "OrderSelectionConfiguration": {
      "SelectionDaysInterval": 30,
      "SelectionDaysMaximum": 365
    }
  }
}
```

it it works fine. Do you have any idea, why setting **PropertyName** on **JsonProperty** does not seem to have any effect?

Comment: When you debug and you call `var serializedConfiguration = this.ConfigurationSection.Get<RecognitionConfiguration>();` do the values exist in the object at that point in time before trying to register the children?

Comment: @KieranDevlin I have edited my post to show you.

Comment: Edit your [mcve] and remove Autofac from it. The part of interest is `ConfigurationSection.Get<RecognitionConfiguration>()` as well as the json that should be deserialized. The fact that the properties are `null` has nothing to do with Autofac, leaving this in your question just adds noise.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for your feedback. I have refactored my post.

Comment: @rbr94 that is by design. Binding to POCO via configuration is not like Model Binding to Action parameters. It matches property names on the POCO to keys in the provided JSON. Read up here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-to-a-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is by design. Binding to POCO via configuration is done by convention. Not like Model Binding to Controller Action parameters.

It matches property names on the POCO to keys in the provided JSON.

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-to-a-class)

So either you change the settings to match the class like you showed in the original question, or change the class to match the settings keys in the Json-based configuration file.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class RecognitionConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PostProcessing", Required = Required.Always)]
    public PostRecognitionConfiguration PostProcessing{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Processing", Required = Required.Always)]
    public ProcessRecognitionConfiguration Processing{ get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class PostRecognitionConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ValidationHandlerConfiguration ValidationHandlerConfiguration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty] 
    public List<string> MatchingCharacterRemovals { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ProcessRecognitionConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "OrderSelection", Required = Required.Always)]
    public OrderSelectionConfiguration OrderSelection { get; set; }
}

public partial class ValidationHandlerConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty("MinimumTrustLevel")]
    public long MinimumTrustLevel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MinimumMatchingTrustLevel")]
    public long MinimumMatchingTrustLevel { get; set; }
}


public partial class OrderSelectionConfiguration {
    [JsonProperty("SelectionDaysInterval")]
    public long SelectionDaysInterval { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SelectionDaysMaximum")]
    public long SelectionDaysMaximum { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It's really helpful! I'd hoped for a solution where it is possible to assign custom property names like in newtonsoft

Comment: While my answer can solve OP's problem, I do not think (yet) any situation that requires the complexity involved. I highly recommend using this one if possible.

Comment: A question around this... The [JsonProperty] and [JsonObject] properties now become meaningless?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found this one is much more pleasant than my previous solutions: Bind everything in an `ExpandoObject`, write them to JSON and use JSON.NET to bind them back. [Using the code of this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007146/bind-netcore-iconfigurationsection-to-a-dynamic-object):

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
{

    public static class ConfigurationBinder
    {

        public static void BindJsonNet(this IConfiguration config, object instance)
        {
            var obj = BindToExpandoObject(config);

            var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonText, instance);
        }

        private static ExpandoObject BindToExpandoObject(IConfiguration config)
        {
            var result = new ExpandoObject();

            // retrieve all keys from your settings
            var configs = config.AsEnumerable();
            foreach (var kvp in configs)
            {
                var parent = result as IDictionary<string, object>;
                var path = kvp.Key.Split(':');

                // create or retrieve the hierarchy (keep last path item for later)
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < path.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (!parent.ContainsKey(path[i]))
                    {
                        parent.Add(path[i], new ExpandoObject());
                    }

                    parent = parent[path[i]] as IDictionary<string, object>;
                }

                if (kvp.Value == null)
                    continue;

                // add the value to the parent
                // note: in case of an array, key will be an integer and will be dealt with later
                var key = path[i];
                parent.Add(key, kvp.Value);
            }

            // at this stage, all arrays are seen as dictionaries with integer keys
            ReplaceWithArray(null, null, result);

            return result;
        }

        private static void ReplaceWithArray(ExpandoObject parent, string key, ExpandoObject input)
        {
            if (input == null)
                return;

            var dict = input as IDictionary<string, object>;
            var keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();

            // it's an array if all keys are integers
            if (keys.All(k => int.TryParse(k, out var dummy)))
            {
                var array = new object[keys.Length];
                foreach (var kvp in dict)
                {
                    array[int.Parse(kvp.Key)] = kvp.Value;
                }

                var parentDict = parent as IDictionary<string, object>;
                parentDict.Remove(key);
                parentDict.Add(key, array);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var childKey in dict.Keys.ToList())
                {
                    ReplaceWithArray(input, childKey, dict[childKey] as ExpandoObject);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        var settings = new MySettings();
        this.Configuration.BindJsonNet(settings);
```

Here is my testing `MySettings` class:

```
public class MySettings
{

    [JsonProperty("PostProcessing")]
    public SomeNameElseSettings SomenameElse { get; set; }

    public class SomeNameElseSettings
    {

        [JsonProperty("ValidationHandlerConfiguration")]
        public ValidationHandlerConfigurationSettings WhateverNameYouWant { get; set; }

        public class ValidationHandlerConfigurationSettings
        {

            [JsonProperty("MinimumTrustLevel")]
            public int MinimumTrustLevelFoo { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("MinimumMatchingTrustLevel")]
            public int MinimumMatchingTrustLevelBar { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

After the calling, I get everything as you desired:

[image]

---

Old Answer:

According to the [source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Config.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L209), it is simply (near) impossible to do what you are requiring. I have tried both `JsonProperty` and `DataContract`, none of which are honored by the Binder, simply because the source code itself simply use the property name.

If you still insist, there are 2 possibilities, however I do not recommend any as changing properties' names are much simpler:

- Fork your source code there, or simply copy that file (in my attempt to trace the code, I rename all methods to something like `Bind2`, `BindInstance2` etc), and rewrite the code accordingly.
- This one is very specific to current implementation, so it's not future-proof: the current code is calling `config.GetSection(property.Name)`, so you can write your own `IConfiguration` and provide your own name for `GetSection` method and tap it into the bootstrap process instead of using the default one.

Comment: Is it possible to use htis to serialize just 1 section?

Comment: @GradynWursten Yes, simply put the section (property) name in the code above and ignore the rest. However IMO it's just simpler to just make a proper POCO class with correct "schema" and then copy over.

Answer (score -1):

Changing `PropertyName` on `JsonProperty` does have effect. Here is the same I tried and it did worked for me:

my JSON data:

```
{"name": "John","age": 30,"cars": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]}
```

and the Model:

```
public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="name")]
        public string Apple { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public List<string> cars { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the code:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

and this is the output i get

[image]

You need to set the `PropertyName` in `JsonProperty` same as json file property name but your C# model property can be what you wanted, just that they need to be decorated with `[JsonProperty(PropertyName ="jsonPropertyName")]` Hope this helps you solve your issue.

Happy coding...

Comment: I don't think this faces the problem on my question. It's no problem with deserialization with Newtonsoft, but with the `Get<>` extension of `IConfigurationSection`